# Auto restart programs using perl script

Tags: windows, perl, variables, batch-file, telnet

I run a game server on a windows 2008 r2 machine and I am trying to set up an auto restart script to run every 12 hours, So far I am using windows task scheduler to load a Perl script every 12 hours which connects to telnet in order to let the players know the server is restarting, then when the script is done it closes and my second task scheduler runs a .bat to kill open tasks and restarts them, What I want to do is kill the process and then restart the same processes using just the perl script so the .bat would not be needed.

So I have been googling like crazy and coming up empty, I am very new to using Perl so the things I have found in google based on what I want to do are all using the PID to kill a running task. I did a test with opening and closing a saved txt file to see if the process id changes each time its opened and it seems it does. So using the PID would not work unless there is a workaround for this.

Here is the Telnet connection if anyone can help me clean this up as well so there are not so many prints and maybe call on variables instead it to make this a bit simpler it would help as as well.

```
$hostname = "IP_HERE";

use Net::Telnet ();
    $t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 60,
                          Prompt => '/bash\$ $/');
    $t->open(Host => $hostname,
               Port => PORT_HERE);
    $t->waitfor('/Please enter password/');            
    $t->print("PASSWORD_HERE");
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]3 MINUTES[FFFFFF] !!!\" ");
    sleep(60);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]2 MINUTES[FFFFFF] !!!\" ");
    sleep(60);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]1 MINUTE[FFFFFF] !!!\" ");
    sleep(45);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]15 SECONDS[FFFFFF] !!!\" ");
    sleep(15);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]5\" ");
    sleep(1);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]4\" ");
    sleep(1);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]3\" ");
    sleep(1);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]2\" ");
    sleep(1);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]1\" ");
    sleep(1);
    $t->print("sa");
    sleep(3);
    $t->print("shutdown");
    sleep(3);
exit;
```

If anyone can get me started in the right direction it would mean a lot, I have checked out System and a few other things but no matter what I find it always shows ending a process by PID and not the process name. and nothing has shown me the correct way of loading the program back up based on the directory its in.

Answer (score 0):

I came across something that look promising but not sure how I would call on two different running processes. Any thoughts?

```
$|++;
system("WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\\log.txt path win32_process get Processid,Commandline");
$infile1="C:/log.txt";
open(IN1,"<:encoding(UTF-16LE)","$infile1");
$profilename="ts3client_win64.exe";
while(<IN1>)
{
            next if (/^(\s)*$/);
            s/(\s)+$//g;
            if (/$profilename/)
            {
            print "$1\n" if (m/(\d+)$/);
            system("taskkill /F /PID $1");
            }
}
close(IN1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Been working with this for hours now and not getting an answer I have not tested the below code so no idea if it will work yet but I am posting it here to see if anyone has any input on this and if it looks correct before I use it. What it does is starts a telnet connection and then sends a message to online players to let them know the server is restarting then it saves the servers info using a command "sa" and then shuts down the server using the "shutdown" command, The next few parts is where I am most confused.

The second part it should close the servers exe and the managers exe then start deleting files from a directory before reloading the manager and server again. This is what I have so far please leave some feed back and let me know if it is correct or if there is a simpler way of doing all of this.

```
$hostname = "SERVER_IP_HERE";
use Net::Telnet ();
    $t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 60,
                          Prompt => '/bash\$ $/');
    $t->open(Host => $hostname,
               Port => SERVER_PORT_HERE);
    $t->waitfor('/Please enter password/');            
    $t->print("SERVER_PASSWORD_HERE");
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]3 MINUTES[FFFFFF] !!!\" ");
    sleep(60);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]2 MINUTES[FFFFFF] !!!\" ");
    sleep(60);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]1 MINUTE[FFFFFF] !!!\" ");
    sleep(45);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]15 SECONDS[FFFFFF] !!!\" ");
    sleep(10);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]5\" ");
    sleep(1);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]4\" ");
    sleep(1);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]3\" ");
    sleep(1);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]2\" ");
    sleep(1);
    $t->print("say \"[FF0000]WARNING! [FF0000]SERVER WILL RESTART IN [FF0000]1\" ");
    sleep(1);
    $t->print("sa");
    sleep(2);
    $t->print("shutdown");
    sleep(3);
$|++;
system("WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\\log.txt path win32_process get Processid,Commandline");
$infile1="C:/log.txt";
open(IN1,"<:encoding(UTF-16LE)","$infile1");
$server="SERVERS.exe";
$servermanager="SERVERMANAGERS.EXE";
while(<IN1>)
{
            next if (/^(\s)*$/);
            s/(\s)+$//g;
            if (/$server/)
            {
            print "$1\n" if (m/(\d+)$/);
            system("taskkill /F /PID $1");
            }
            if (/$servermanager/)
            {
            print "$1\n" if (m/(\d+)$/);
            system("taskkill /F /PID $1");
            }
}
close(IN1);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-1.0.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.0.0.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.0.-5.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.1.-5.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-4.-9.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-4.-10.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-3.-9.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-3.-10.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.7.-4.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.7.-5.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.14.-14.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.14.-13.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.38.-9.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.39.-9.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-10.3.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-9.3.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-10.2.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-9.2.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-21.1.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-21.0.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-22.1.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-22.0.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.17.-2.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.16.-2.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.16.-1.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.10.7.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.9.7.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.8.7.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.10.8.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.9.8.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.8.8.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-11.10.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-10.10.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-11.9.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-10.9.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.1.17.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-4.19.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-3.19.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.12.24.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.11.24.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.12.23.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-22.18.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-21.18.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-22.17.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-21.17.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-21.16.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-17.29.7rg”);
sleep(1);  
unlink (“D:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\r.-17.28.7rg”);
sleep(1);   
system("c:\\FULL\\PATH\\TO\\PROGRAM\\.EXE"); 
exit;
```